# Find customer buying a product after purchasing another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a business logic question that I do not know how to correctly formulate the sql statement to retrieve it. I will simplify the business model for easier discussion.
I have a table recording which customers have bought what product and on what day.

[image]

There is a need to find out the instances of customer(s) who have purchased product B after having purchased product A. I came up with the query below:

```
select t."Customer",t."Date" "Date2", t."Product" "Product2",a.*
from
(
select "Customer","Date", "Product"
from test2 where "Product"='A'
) a,
test2 t
where a."Customer"= t."Customer" and t."Product"='B' and t."Date">=a."Date"
```

It is not quite right as it has over counted the instances because if we look at the table, customer 1 have bought B after buying A in 2 occasions but my query has counted 3 times

[image]

The instance I circled should not be counted.
Is there a way to fix this?
I have attached a script to create the table TEST2 for your convenience.

```
  CREATE TABLE  "TEST2" 
   (    "Customer" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "Date" DATE, 
    "Product" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
   );

Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('1',to_date('07-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('1',to_date('07-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'B');
Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('1',to_date('17-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('1',to_date('27-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR'),'B');
Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('2',to_date('26-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into  TEST2 ("Customer","Date","Product") values ('3',to_date('01-OCT-18','DD-MON-RR'),'C');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on 12c or higher, you can do this with [pattern matching (match_recognize)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST2 (    
  customer      VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
  purchase_date DATE, 
  Product       VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
);

Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('1',to_date('07-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('1',to_date('07-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'B');
Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('1',to_date('17-AUG-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('1',to_date('27-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR'),'B');
Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('2',to_date('26-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR'),'A');
Insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) values ('3',to_date('01-OCT-18','DD-MON-RR'),'C');
commit;

select * from test2
match_recognize (
  partition by customer
  order by purchase_date, product
  measures
    proda.purchase_date prod_a_date,
    prodb.purchase_date prod_b_date
  pattern ( proda prodb )
  define
    proda as product = 'A',
    prodb as product = 'B'
);

CUSTOMER    PROD_A_DATE             PROD_B_DATE            
1           07-AUG-2018 00:00:00    07-AUG-2018 00:00:00    
1           17-AUG-2018 00:00:00    27-SEP-2018 00:00:00
```

This says:

- For each customer (`partition by customer`)
- Sorted by purchase date and product (`order by purchase_date, product`)
- Find instances of product A followed immediately by product B (`pattern ( proda prodb )`)
- The `define` section states what the products are

The pattern is a regular expression. You can redefine the variables to search for any product you want (or make the product values bind variables - `proda as product = :bindvar`).

If you need to find instances of B after A with other product purchases in-between, you can use the exclusion syntax ( {-var-} ):

```
insert into TEST2 (customer,purchase_date,product) 
  values ('1',to_date('20-SEP-18','DD-MON-RR'),'C');

select * from test2
match_recognize (
  partition by customer
  order by purchase_date, product
  measures
    proda.purchase_date prod_a_date,
    prodb.purchase_date prod_b_date
  pattern ( proda {-otherprod*-} prodb )
  define
    proda as product = 'A',
    prodb as product = 'B',
    otherprod as product not in ( 'A', 'B' )
);

CUSTOMER    PROD_A_DATE             PROD_B_DATE            
1           07-AUG-2018 00:00:00    07-AUG-2018 00:00:00    
1           17-AUG-2018 00:00:00    27-SEP-2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: That is awesome, @chris!!! This is exactly the solution I am trying to find but not smart enough to see it. Thank you soooo much!!!!

Comment: The pattern matching is really powerful and I am very new to it. I would like to have a quick follow up because I have simplified my issue to form the question. If my model does not only include 3 fields but also has a product description, do I need to do another link of the results to the product table or can I include it in the results?

Comment: The `measures` clause defines the output columns, so add it there. Or if you change to `all rows per match` it shows you all the rows in the group and all the input columns

Comment: Yep, I figure out to use measures... took me a little while to figure that out but it is all good... the solution you suggested is exactly what I need. Worked like a charm!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select customer
from test2
group by customer
having min(case when product = 'A' then date end) < max(case when product = 'B' then date end);
```

If you want the dates, just add the functions in the `having` to the `select`.

Comment: Thank for the hint. However, just listing the customer only is not an issue. My sql does work as well. The issue comes in when user what to see the products and dates. In my simplified model, I only list A as the only product, in reality, it is a subset of product like A,C,F... so, user would like to know what is the specific product that triggered the purchase of B to do further analysis